# Finding a vector space or group structure on a set of complex 4-tuples

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, binary-operations

Consider the set of 4-tuples of complex numbers $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ for which 
$$\Im\left(  -\frac{-y_1 x_1-y_2 x_2}{x_1^2+x_2^2} \right)=0 \tag{1}$$
and
$$\Im\left(\frac{i (y_1 x_2-y_2 x_1)}{x_1^2+x_2^2}\right)=0 \tag{2}$$
(1) and (2) are equivalent to the condition that there exist *some* real $a,b$ such that
$$
\left[\begin{matrix} a & i b \\ - i b & a \end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix} y_1\\ y_2 \end{matrix}\right] \tag{3}
$$
(1) and (2) are what you get by solving (3) for $a,b$ and demanding they are real.

This is a somewhat open-ended question: I hope to find some sort of vector space or group structure on this set, (or even just a binary operation), something that would allow me to find a third 4-tuple that obeys (1) and (2), given two 4-tuples that obey (1) and (2).

Some thoughts: Clearly, if $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ obeys (1) and (2), then so does any multiple $(r x_1,r x_2,r y_1,r y_2)$ for any complex $r$. So, a useful reformulation might be
$$ (r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta),r y_1,r y_2)$$
with both $r$ and $\theta$ complex. Then (1) and (2) reduce to 
$$\Im\left(  y_1 \cos(\theta)+y_2 \sin(\theta) \right)=0 $$
$$\Im\left(  [y_1,y_2]\cdot [\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)] \right)=0 $$
and
$$\Re\left(-y_1 \sin(\theta)+y_2 \cos(\theta)\right)=0 $$
$$\Re\left(  [y_1,y_2]\cdot [-\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta)] \right)=0 $$